# Load library class with parameter constructor by autoload.php CI

Tags: php, codeigniter, constructor

I have created library class as mentioned below:

```
class FrontLayout {

var $obj;
var $layout;

  function FrontLayout($layout) {
    $this->obj = & get_instance();
    $this->layout = $layout;
    $this->obj->load->library("Session");
    $this->obj->load->config("config");
  }
}
```

I am trying to load a library class ( it have parameter constructor)by passing parameter:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('frontlayout'=>'layout/theme1');
```

What is the correct way to load parameterized constructor in autoload.php file?

Comment: Check if [this thread](https://forum.codeigniter.com/archive/index.php?thread-62217.html) is helpful for you.

Comment: yes it worked for me....

Comment: Great Happy coding.